# These are the very words that testify about me" what does the phrase mean

Tags: jesus

Considering the following scriptures

> John 5:39 BSB You pore over the Scriptures because you presume that by
> them you possess eternal life. These are the very words that testify
> about Me,
>
> John 1:45 BSB Philip found Nathanael and told him, “We have found the
> One Moses wrote about in the Law, the One the prophets foretold—Jesus
> of Nazareth, the son of Joseph.”

It seems that the whole of Scriptures points to and is talking about Jesus.

Is this the best interpretation from these texts?

Comment: Your question is too broad and off-topic. For instance, the [Tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) provides the guideline "*Ask about ... Interpretation of a specific passage*", yet your post does not mention specific passage(s). Alternatively, you might want to post on Christianity SE, although I presume your question *as is* would still be considered too broad over there.

Comment: The scriptures are not too broad.  The whole scripture Testify of Jesus.  They Testify of Jesus as whAt?

Comment: "*The scriptures are not too broad.*" Yes, they are. And [your edit](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/revisions/80189/2) seems very unlikely to prevent the post from getting closed as off-topic, since it does not fit the type of questions for which the site is intended.

Comment: Sighs.. I have changed the question totally.  I wished I had a place to ask the previous question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jesus is the beginning, middle and end point of the entire Bible, not only because He is God but also because He is our Messiah, Saviour, Mediator, High Priest and King.  Jesus is the sum and substance of all true theology, Luke 24:27, John 5:39, 3:14, 6:32-35, 12:8, 14:6, 1 Cor 10:4, 15:3-7, 2 Cor 1:20, Ps 19:1, Heb 12:2, 3, 1 John 5:11, 12, Rev 1:1, etc.  All theology must illuminate Jesus in some significant way; further all heterodox teaching is such only because it detracts from the true identity of Jesus.

The OT contains (depending on how one counts them) between 40-60 detailed prophecies of Jesus and His life.  Further, many of the stories in the Bible are clearly constructed to make them types of Jesus. (Christological Typology is another Bible discipline entirely.)

Stated another way, The only valid theology is some aspect of Christology.

- Jesus is our Great High Priest (ἀρχιερεύς = leading priest, Heb 3:1, 4:14, 8:1, etc) who is head/leader of the royal priesthood (ἱεράτευμα, 1 Peter 2:5, 9), the church of Jesus Christ who are thus denoted as “priests” (ἱερεύς, hiereus)
- Jesus is our King (Luke 1:33, John 1:49, Acts 13:23, Rev 11:15) of the Holy nation (1 Peter 2:5, 9), His church.
- Jesus is “Lord of Lords” (Rev 17:14, 19:16) and “Lord of All” (Acts 10:36, Rom 10:12, Col 1:15).
- Jesus the Great Shepherd (ἀρχιποίμην, 1 Peter 5:4, see also John 10:11, 14) and we are the sheep of His pasture (John 10:4, 27, 1 Peter 2:25, Ps 95:7, 100:3, etc), His church
- Jesus is the great Overseer (1 Peter 2:25) of us all, His church
- Jesus is our great Example (John 13:15, 1 Peter 2:21, 1 Tim 1:16) that we follow ("Christians" are those who are like Christ) to create His church
- Jesus is also the Great Apostle, Heb 3:1 (see also John 5:23, 6:29, 38, 17:18, etc).
- Jesus is the First & Last, Rev 1:17, 18, 2:8, 22:13.
- Jesus set an example of how to love (John 13:34, 35, 1 John 4:8, 16) that we should love as He loves us
- Jesus is the chief cornerstone or “capstone” (Eph 2:19-22, 1 Peter 2:4-8, Acts 4:11, Matt 21:42, Mark 12:10, Luke 20:17) with the members of the Christian community are bricks in the temple of God (1 Cor 3:10-17, Rev 3:12).
- Jesus is “our brother” (Heb 2:11-13, Ps 22:22, Isa 8:17, 18, Matt 12:48, 49, John 20:17, Rom 8:29) and thus, close to all of us.
- Jesus is the Light of the World (John 1:9, 8:12, 9:5, 1 John 1:5-7) and we are to reflect that light to the world (Matt 5:14-16).
- Jesus is the great Reconciler of Man with God (Rom 5:10, 2 Cor 5:19, Col 1:20, 22) via His ministry as Advocate (parakletos, 1 John 2:1), Mediator (mesites, 1 Tim 2:5, Heb 8:6, 9:15, 12:24), and Intercessor (eutunchano, Rom 8:34, Heb 7:25).  See also Heb 9:24.
- Jesus is the “Word of God”, John 1:1-3, 14, Rev 19:13. See also Heb 4:12, 2 Peter 3:5, 1 John 5:7.

Thus, the only really valid question in Biblical theology is, Who is Jesus?

Comment: Profound!   Who is Jesus?.. That's the only valid question

Answer (score 0):

Hebrews 10:5 appears to assert that Jesus quoted Ps 40:6-8 some time during his ministry (though none of the gospels contain this quote), and if so, then His assertion "As it is written of me/In the scroll of the book" would seem to support your interpretation of the texts you quoted.